# Bash Shell: Can't use arrow key (up/down) to check command history

Tags: bash, shell

Press up/down key in the shell and nothing happened. How can I check this? I config the system capture the up/down pressed correctly when I press them.

```bash
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue resolved after I update HISTSIZE/HISTSIZE env variables in my bash shell from 0xFFFFFFFF to a smaller value.

Comment: Why do you use hex notation? And why do you want your history to contain **four** **billion** **two** **hundred** **ninety-four** **million** **nine** **hundred** **sixty-seven** **thousand** **two** **hundred** **ninety-five** entries?? Most users never need bigger HISTSIZE than 10k-20k entries...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).